# Yii2 Gii write own sql to filter data

Tags: php, sql, yii2, yii2-basic-app, gii

I used gii in yii2 to generate a crud system.
I need to write this sql to filter correct data in table.

`$date_now = date('Y-m-d');`

`$query = "SELECT *  FROM reservation_db WHERE  STR_TO_DATE(`date`,'%d-%m-%Y') > '$date_now'";`

I know this is wrong, I save date as type text in database. So, I need using STR_TO_DATE to convert from string to date and make sql only select data greater then today.

Any idea where I do this sql?

Here is my ReservationSearch Model

```
 <?php

 namespace app\models;

 use Yii;
 use yii\base\Model;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use app\models\ReservationDb;
```

/**
   * ReservationSearch represents the model behind the search form about 
   `app\models\ReservationDb`.
   */
  class ReservationSearch extends ReservationDb
  {
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['reservation_id', 'adult', 'child', 'infat', 'phone_num'], 
        'integer'],
            [['name', 'date', 'time', 'session', 'seat_area', 'remark', 
       'payment_status', 'reservation_date'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function scenarios()
{
    // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
    return Model::scenarios();
}

/**
 * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
 *
 * @param array $params
 *
 * @return ActiveDataProvider
 */
public function search($params)
{
    $date_now = date('Y-m-d');

    $query = ReservationDb::find();
    $query->andFilterCompare( 'STR_TO_DATE(date)', '$date_now', '>');





    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any 
    records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'reservation_id' => $this->reservation_id,
        'adult' => $this->adult,
        'child' => $this->child,
        'infat' => $this->infat,
        'phone_num' => $this->phone_num,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->name])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'date', $this->date])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'time', $this->time])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'session', $this->session])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'seat_area', $this->seat_area])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'remark', $this->remark])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'payment_status', $this->payment_status])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'reservation_date', $this-
      >reservation_date]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

}

Comment: In `ReservationSearch` model.

Comment: yes, I tried a few way in ReservationSearch. like `$query->andFilterCompare('STR_TO_DATE(date)', '>$date_now');`

Comment: or `        $query = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select('*')
        ->from('reservation_db')
        ->where(['reservation_id' => '457'])
        ->all();
        */`

Comment: even I only try to select ID its return me this error `Call to a member function andFilterWhere() on a non-object`

Comment: Try `$query->andFilterCompare([ 'STR_TO_DATE(date)',  $date_now,  '>' ])`

Comment: @Insane Skull Thank for your help, but I got this error when I using that code `Missing argument 2 for yii\db\Query::andFilterCompare()` from this function  `public function andFilterCompare($name, $value, $defaultOperator = '=')`

Comment: add `ReservationSearch` model.

Comment: Instead of many comment should be better a simple answer ..

Comment: @Insane Skull yes, I got a model call ResercationSearch model and I write these code inside

Comment: I success to run `$query->andFilterCompare([ STR_TO_DATE(date), $date_now, '>' ])` but I got this error `Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'STR_TO_DATE'
The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reservation_db WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date) > '$date_now'`

Comment: Update your question with `ReservationSearch ` model.

Comment: @Insane Skull Updated

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public function search($params)
{
   $date_now = date('Y-m-d');

   $query = ReservationDb::find();
   $query->andFilterCompare('STR_TO_DATE(date)', $date_now, '>');
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Comment: Hi @Insane Skull here is the error `Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'STR_TO_DATE'
The SQL being executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reservation_db WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date) > '2017-06-29'`

Comment: I think STR_TO_DATE is not working for select count(*) ?